# how to hide ttk button

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkinter for my application (written in Python).
Till now I've needed only "next" button so I didnt have a problem, but now I want to add a screen (after several "next") where I'm asking a yes/no question so I want to have 2 buttons for "yes" and "no" and that the next button will disapear, and after that it will be returned and the others will disapeared.
Is there a way to do that?
TNX

Comment: See tutorial about frames [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBUpjijYtCk)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that shows what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Use `your_button.pack_forget()` for that. If you are using another place manager just use `place_forget` or `grid_forget` method.

Comment: If this answer helped you feel free to mark it with green checkmark as an answer.